# About the connected-étale sequence for finite group schemes over a complete noetherian local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, group-schemes

Let $R$ be a complete noetherian local ring and $G$ be a finite group scheme over $R$ (that is a group scheme over $\operatorname{Spec}(R)$ whose structure morphism is finite locally free, or equivalently here, finite flat). As detailed in the notes "finite flat group schemes" by Tate, there is a canonical exact sequence 
$$0\rightarrow G^0 \rightarrow G\rightarrow G^{ét}\rightarrow 0$$
where $G^0$ is the identity component of $G$, it is a finite connected group over $R$, and $G^{ét}$ is the quotient, it is a finite étale group over $R$.

In the other paper "p-divisible group", Tate states that in general, we have an identification $G^{ét}=G(\overline{k})$ where $\overline{k}$ is an algebraic closure of the residue field $k$ of $R$.

I am confused by this last statement. First of all, $G^{ét}$ is a group scheme over $R$ whereas $G(\overline{k})$ is, to my knowledge, just an abstract group whence I don't know how to interpret this equality.

Moreover, in all generality if $X$ is a scheme defined over a basis ring $A$ and $L$ is an $A$-algebra which is also a field, then the $L$-valued points $X(L)$ of $X$ are in natural identification with pairs $(x,\phi)$ where $x\in |X|$ and $\phi: \kappa(x)\rightarrow L$ is a field extension, $\kappa(x)$ being the residue field of $x$.
Now if $X$ is a group scheme $G$, it is a homogeneous space over itself by translation, hence all points of $G$ have the same local ring, so the same residue field as well. Whence, if $G$ has an $L$-valued point, then all its points are $L$-valued.

If I take this observation into account (and if it is true), then the identity $G^{ét}=G(\overline k)$ would imply $G^{ét}=G$ or $G^{ét}$ is trivial according to whether there is a $\overline{k}$-valued point or not. This conclusion does not sound right to me, hence there must be a mistake in my understanding.

Could somebody please help me clarify the situation here ?

Comment: My guess is that the identity of $G=Spec(A),A=R[x]/(x^6-1),R=\Bbb{Z}_2$ corresponds to the maximal ideal $(2,x-1)$ then the connected component are the prime ideals contained in it ie. $(x-1),(x+1)$, their intersection is $(x^2-1)$ so $G^0=Spec(A/(x^2-1))$ and $G/G^0$ can be identified with $Spec(A/(2))$ ie. to $G(\overline{\Bbb{F}}_2)$ (or is it $G/G^0 = Spec(A^\sigma)$ where $\sigma(x)=-x$ ?)

Comment: Thank you very much for your very nice example @reuns. I can see better how this works. After some more thoughts, I think that the identity $G^{ét}=G(\overline k)$ is maybe to be understood in the following way: by a theorem of Grothendieck, there is an equivalence of categories between finite étale group schemes over $R$ and finite $\pi$-module with continuous action, where $\pi = Gal(\overline k/k)$. For a general $G$, the group $G(\overline k)$ is such a $\pi$-module ; whence it corresponds to some finite étale group which must precisely be $G^{ét}$.